# How do I shuffle a deque?

Tags: java, shuffle, deque

This is my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Deque;
import java.util.List;

public class ArrayDequeDemo {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

      // create an empty array deque with an initial capacity
      Deque<Integer> deque = new ArrayDeque<Integer>(8);

      // use add() method to add elements in the deque
      deque.add(15);
      deque.add(30);
      deque.add(20);
      deque.add(18);        

      // let us print all the elements available in deque
      for (Integer number : deque) {
         System.out.println("Number = " + number);
      }

      //Collections.shuffle((List<?>) deque);
      // getFirst() will retrieve element at first(head) position
      int retval = deque.getFirst();
      System.out.println("Retrieved Element is = " + retval);
   }
}
```

I know how to shuffle a `List`, but how do I use the `Collections` to shuffle a deque?
Please reply with code as I am not totally used to Java terms/theory, I am still learning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use `java.util.Collections` to shuffle a `Deque`; it only works on collections that implement `List`. You can write your own shuffle routine or you can first create a `List`, shuffle it, and then copy the results to a `Deque`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

  // create an empty array deque with an initial capacity
  List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(8);

  // use add() method to add elements in the deque
  list.add(15);
  list.add(30);
  list.add(20);
  list.add(18);        

  // let us print all the elements available in deque
  for (Integer number : list) {
     System.out.println("Number = " + number);
  }

  Collections.shuffle(list);
  Deque<Integer> deque = new ArrayDeque<Integer>(list);
  // getFirst() will retrieve element at first(head) position
  int retval = deque.getFirst();
  System.out.println("Retrieved Element is = " + retval);
}
```

The problem with writing your own shuffle routine, of course, is that the `Deque` interface does not provide a means of moving elements around.

Comment: Thanks! I will pick this as the answer :) Quick question, reading other answers I see this: `Note that Deque is only the Interface, to Shuffle use a class that also implements List then you can use Collections.shuffle(List)` Is that what you have done above?

Comment: @Ryan - Exactly. If you want a single concrete collection type that implements both `List` and `Deque`, you can used a `LinkedList`. Note that array-based collections have O(1) access time to random elements while `LinkedList` is O(n). (Shuffling an `ArrayList` is faster than shuffling a `LinkedList`.) However, for straight iteration or for repeated operations at the start and/or end, `LinkedList` has just as good (and sometimes better) performance compared to array-based collections.

Comment: Generally not really much point to "writing your own", unless it's absolutely performance-critical. The canonical answer for shuffling would probably be to do it in an ArrayList (since shuffling requires random-access), and then copy it back to the LinkedList/ Deque. Collections.shuffle() shuffles non random-access lists in an array, for this reason.

Answer (score 3):

Collections.shuffle(List) accepts only List so in order to shuffle Deque you need to use LinkedList implementation of Deque. LinkedList implements both Deque and List interfaces. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/deque.html

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();

    // use add() method to add elements in the deque
    list.add(15);
    list.add(30);
    list.add(20);
    list.add(18);

    // let us print all the elements available in deque
    for (Integer number : list) {
        System.out.println("Number = " + number);
    }

    Collections.shuffle(list);
    int retval = list.getFirst();
    System.out.println("Retrieved Element is = " + retval);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, will check out the link you posted. I kind of already knew how to do it with a List, but the deque part was puzzling to me. +1'ed.